# Как определить, что сборка является Single-file?

Tags: c#, .net-core

В `.NET Core` (вроде с 3-ей версии) есть так называемый [Single-file Publish](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/master/accepted/2020/single-file/design.md), который позволяет собрать весь проект в один выходной файл, который также может в себе содержать и сам .NET Core, что позволяет не устанавливать его у клиента.

Собственно в планах делать его "самообновляемым", но увы, не каждый в состояние качать "много" из интернета, у некоторых либо до сих пор трафик, либо скорость очень мала, либо еще ряд других проблем. А сам проект, если его собрать по такой технологии, начинает весить не 100кб, а 150мб++.

Для решения данной проблемы, было принято делать две публикации:

- **Минимальная** - не содержит в себе .NET Core и вес от 100кб
- **Максимальная** - в составе .NET Core, ну и вес 100мб и выше.

И тут уже пусть сами клиенты решают какой способ им удобней и что они хотят. НО! Как быть с автоматическим обновлением? Нужно понимать какая версия стоит у клиента.

**Собственно вопрос:** Как можно определить, "максимальная" у человека версия, или "минимальная"? Как узнать, есть ли в этом .exe файле сам .NET Сore?
Можно конечно попробовать по размеру определять, но это прям костыль какой-то. Можно записывать в файлик информацию, но тоже как по мне не то.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112647/discussion-on-question-by-evgeniyz------single-fi).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать `DefineConstants` для того, чтобы при сборке разных версий проекта указать какая это версии и на основании этого и выбирать тип обновления.

Например:

При сборке вызывать `dotnet build -p:DefineConstants=SINGLEFILE ...`.
А в коде проверять это при помощи `#if SINGLEFILE ...`.

Также можно эти все настройки поместить в `*.csproj`, чтобы каждый раз не указывать в консоли или при изменении не бегать по всем билд скриптам.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <!-- дефолтные опции, которые будет использоваться -->
    <!-- для всех "типов" сборок -->
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'SINGLEFILE'">
    <ConfigurationGroup>Release</ConfigurationGroup>
    <DefineConstants>SINGLEFILE</DefineConstants>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>osx-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'MAX'">
    <ConfigurationGroup>Release</ConfigurationGroup>
    <DefineConstants>MAX</DefineConstants>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>osx-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

И теперь можно собирать это как обычный проект:

- `dotnet build` - обычная `Debug` соборка без каких либо оптимизаций и упаковок
- `dotnet build -c SINGLEFILE` - упаковка без `.NET Core`
- `dotnet build -c MAX` - упаковка с `.NET Core`